# How to save an Expando object field with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a class with an ExpandoObject field to allow users of my class
to add their properties to it.

```
public class Employee
{
    public dynamic ExtendedProperties = new ExpandoObject();

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map these extended properties to columns in the database.
How can I save these extended properties with Entity Framework Core 2.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would map this to an XML or JSON column in the database and use an EF Core [Value Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions).